# I dont have ios as an option in Titanium Appcelarator configure dashboard

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, dashboard

I have Titanium Appcelerator installed in my Windows xp pc. Also i have Android SDK in my machine. But i dont find IOS as an option in Titanium Dashboard. What may be the reasons and how do i overcome it?

Answer (score 5):

iOS development requires xCode and the iOS SDK.  Due to Apple's rules, these can only be installed on an Apple OS (OSX).

Possible solutions:

1. Buy Apple hardware with an Apple OS installed
2. Virtualize hardware with an installed Apple OS
3. Rent time through a service such as macincloud.com

Comment: Hi StephenFather,
How can I virtualize my machine for Apple OS? And the steps after doing that... Kindly help.....

Comment: Download VMWare Workstation Client 10.0.3
Download OSX Image from Torrent (Use Mavericks 10.9.5 at least)
You should have Windows 7 at least, with min 4 GB RAM or better to have 8GB with min 100GB spare Hard Disk Space
Install VMWare client
Extract OSX image (downloaded via torrent)
Open Image in VMWare and install Mac in VMWare
Then rest of the stuff is to install XCode and Appcelerator Studio